# HTML+CSS. Ширина блочного элемента по его контенту без обтекания.

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Здравствуйте.
Есть несколько `<div>`. В каждом из них разный по ширине контент.
Задача: сделать каждому `<div>` ширину, равную ширине содержимого, без `inline-block`, так как `inline-block` делает `<div>` обтекаемым строчными элементами.
Пробовала:

```
div {
    inline-block;
    clear:both;
}
```

`max-width` не подходит.

Comment: оформите код здесь http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Какой код? Кода нет, так как я не знаю, как его написать, чтобы решить проблему. В вопросе все описано.

Answer (score 1):

Так годится?

```css
div {
  display: inline;
  background: silver;
}

div::before, div::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
```

```html
Тут был текст <div>А потом div</div> И снова текст
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
div{
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}
```

Comment: Не получится...

Comment: Почему?
У меня получилось http://jsfiddle.net/ewatd62r/1/

Comment: Ну так-то да, но в вопросе про текст говорится, а не про элемент. На разметке из моего примера попробуй - там не получится.

Comment: Цитата:
  "Задача: сделать каждому <div> ширину, равную ширине 
содержимого, без inline-block"

Comment: Продолжение цитаты: "так как inline-block делает <div> обтекаемым строчными элементами". В твоём вариант строчных элементов нет - есть только набор тех div'ов, которые надо подогнать по ширине контента.